# Not able to convert foreach and if to Linq for winform control

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I have this below code and I am unable to convert it into a Linq because it is regarding winform controls

```
bool flag = false;
Panel x = (Panel)sender;

foreach(Control item in x.Controls)
{
    if(item is winformcontrol)
    {
       flag = true;
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to convert it to Linq?

Answer (score 1):

Disregarding any other problem conceptual or otherwise

Since all you are doing is checking if a control is of a certain type, the easiest way is to use the [`Enumerable.OfType<TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=net-5.0) method.

> Filters the elements of an `IEnumerable` based on a specified *type*.

Then all that is needed is to call [`Enumerable.Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-5.0)

> Determines whether any element of a *sequence* exists or satisfies a
> condition.

**Example**

```
// lets check our cast and show off the new #9 pattern matching negation
if (sender is not Panel panel)
   throw new InvalidOperationException("Whoops");

var flag = panel
   .Controls
   .OfType<Something>()
   .Any();

...
```

The longer story is, `ControlCollection.Controls` only supports

- IList
- ICollection
- IEnumerable (Non generic)

Not `IEnumerable<T>` so you are limited by what you can call.

However, `IEnumerable<TResult> OfType<TResult>(this IEnumerable source)` can take the non generic `IEnumerable` parameter, and returns an `IEnumerable<T>` giving you access to all of the extension methods you know and love.